# Spring - does creating ClassPathXmlApplicationContext return the same bean everytime

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean that I added a getInstance() method in order to have the bean return an instance outside of Spring. In the getInstance() code, it gets the bean by creating a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext and calling getBean(). If the getInstance() is called 3 times, it will create 3 ClassPathXmlApplicationContext and return the bean 3 times, is it the same bean everytime, since Spring initializes all beans on startup?

To my understanding all beans by default are singleton and are created and initialized once, and when I call getBean, it returns the created instance. Please correct me if I am wrong and how.

```
// simple example
class Test {
    Test test;

    public Test getInstance(){            
        ClassPathXmlApplication context = getApplicationContext();
        test = context.getBean('testBean');            
        return test;
    }
}
```

edit: I want to make sure getInstance() returns the instance of the singleton created by Spring. After reading the link provided in comments, I understand that as long as the getBean is called on the same context, it wont be recreated, I am still unsure of this situation though because it creates a new ClassPath everytime I call getInstance(). I am looking at legacy code and its similar to what I posted, I would imagine we should be using a null check on if test is null, so the ClassPath only gets created once, trying to understand if the legacy code is wrong or I don't understand Spring.

Comment: Please refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484386/different-beans-scope-in-spring

Comment: thanks can you see my edit and comment?

Comment: Yes i can see. Everytime you create new ApplicationContext you will have new `spring singleton` per container. This is how it works. But i dont know what is the purpose to create more than one application context for test environment ?

Comment: You shouldn't be creating an `ApplicationContext` just because you need a bean. You should create the `ApplicationContext` only once and for the remainder use dependency injection. Even better use Spring Boot or the normal `ContextLoaderListener` and/or `DispatcherServlet` to load the context instead of doing it yourself.